# Adicionar uma hora a hora atual

Tags: php, datetime, data

Eu estou a tentar gravar a hora atual do sistema.

Por exemplo a data atual vai ser `01-08-2019 10:34:44` e eu queria essa mesma data, mas acrescentar mais uma hora, ou seja, ficaria `01-08-2019 11:34:44`.

```
$data_pagamento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `DateTime` e adicionar a 1 hora com `modify`.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 hour');
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa é usar [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), que aceita alguns [formatos especiais](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), entre eles `+x hours` para somar horas:

```
$data_pagamento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime('+1 hours'));
```

No caso, a string poderia ser tanto `'+1 hour'` quanto `'+1 hours'`.

---

Você também pode usar [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), que possui o método [`add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) (que por sua vez, recebe um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) com a duração a ser adicionada):

```
$now = new DateTime(); // data/hora atual
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT1H')); // somar 1 hora
$data_pagamento = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Nesse caso, o `DateInterval` recebe uma [duração no formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (`PT1H` equivale a uma duração de 1 hora).

Lembrando que, apesar do nome, [a função `date` retorna uma **string**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-returnvalues) contendo a data/hora no formato indicado. Para obter esta mesma string com `DateTime`, é necessário usar o [método `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Obs: o código acima serviria para adicionar horas a qualquer `DateTime`. Mas se quiser apenas "a data/hora **atual** mais 1 hora", também é possível usar o mesmo formato que `strtotime` aceita:

```
$now = new DateTime('+1 hours'); // data/hora atual + 1 hora
$data_pagamento = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

---

Generalizando para uma quantidade arbitrária de horas:

```
$qtd_horas = 5;

// com DateTime
$now = new DateTime();
$now->add(new DateInterval("PT{$qtd_horas}H"));
$data_pagamento = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// ou
$now = new DateTime("+{$qtd_horas} hours");
$data_pagamento = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// com strtotime
$data_pagamento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime("+{$qtd_horas} hours"));
```

---

Por fim, vale ressaltar que `strtotime` (ou o método [`modify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), conforme sugerido na [resposta do Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400965/112052)) é, na minha opinião, mais simples de entender (a semântica é bem clara quanto ao que está acontecendo: estou somando X horas).

A alternativa com `DateInterval` pode ser confusa para quem não está familiarizado com o formato da ISO 8601. Mas uma vez que você a conhece (e [nem é tão complicada assim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)), também tem uma semântica bem clara.

Já somar números "mágicos" e "arbitrários" como 3600, embora funcione, é a menos simples de entender (já que temos que parar e pensar de onde vem aquele número). Embora "óbvio" para quem está acostumado a tais cálculos, ainda acho que as outras alternativas (`strtotime`, `add` e `modify`) são melhores.

Answer (score 2):

resolvido, consegui resolver da seguinte forma.

```
$data_pagamento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , time()+3600);
```