# Subtrair hora de data e hora PHP

Tags: php, data, time

Pesquisei pela internet e não encontrei nada que me ajude a resolver esse problema. Preciso fazer o seguinte, pegar uma data/hora informada pelo sistema e diminuir 5 horas dela. Exemplo:

`2019-08-29` `02:40`

essa data e hora foram informadas pelo sistema e eu preciso tirar 5 horas dessa data, tirando 5 horas deveria ficar: `2018-08-28` `21:40`, alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.sub.php

Comment: É basicamente [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400966/112052), mas em vez de `add`, use `sub`, e nos casos que tem `'+X hours'`, troque por `'-X hours'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode resilver isso com os objetos de DateTime e DateInterval.

Segue exemplo:

```
<?php
// Intervalo de 5 horas.
$Intervalo = new DateInterval("PT5H");
// P = Periodo que no seu caso não se aplica, pois manipula dias meses e anos
// T = Representação de tempo em horas.
// 5 = O tamanho do intervalo;
// H = Horas

// Data do sistema.
$data = new DateTime();

// Testar o objeto.
print("<pre>");
print("A data atual é: <br>");
print_r($data);
print("</pre>");

// Aplicando a remoçlão de 5 horas.
$data->sub($Intervalo);

// Testar o objeto.
print("<pre>");
print("A nova data é: <br>");
print_r($data);
print("</pre>");
```

A saída da execução será:

```
A data atual é: 
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-08-29 19:53:15.776538
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)

A nova data é: 
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-08-29 14:53:15.776538
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

Espero que ajude...